# What are the radii of the iOS icon corners?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ipod-touch, ios, icon

What are the radii of the iOS icon corners at the various sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of iOS icon templates available for free on the web—the best I've seen so far is from [The Hicksenian](http://hicksdesign.co.uk/journal/ios-icon-template-for-illustrator-cs5)—that will offer up this information (and possibly even obviate the need to know entirely). There is even a (very) short discussion about the corner radii. A quick search for `ios icon template` will return a lot of similar results.